# NestJs: How to access database in entity listeners?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I've got a `@BeforeInsert()` listener in my `Post` entity. The listener is supposed to create a unique slug for the `slug` column before insertion.

For example:

```
export class Post extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    title: string

    @Column()
    slug: string

    @BeforeInsert()
    private updateSlug() {
        this.slug = slugify(this.title)
        // I will need to access the database to check whether the same slug has existsed already or not. 
        // How do I access the database in this listener method?
    }
}
```

Since the `slug` column is supposed to be unique, I will have to check in the database to know whether the same slug already exists. If the slug already exists, I will then need to append a number behind the slug, like `hello-word-1`.

However, to do so, I will need to access the `Post` repository of the entity in the `Post` entity class before I can access the database. But I don't see how I can inject the repository into my `Post` entity class to access the database for this purpose.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: You should not access the repository from your entity, but you can provide an API in a custom repository to do what you need as you can get the entity manager from there. Then you just call the repository from your codebase when you need. Checking the slug before insert is too late to my mind, this is something you should do beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to use dependency injection in typeorm entities, since they are not instantiated by nest. You can however use an [EntitySubscriber](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md) instead which can inject dependencies. See the solution from this [Github issue](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/pull/27#issuecomment-431296683):

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectConnection, InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Connection, EntitySubscriberInterface, InsertEvent, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Post } from '../models';

@Injectable()
export class PostSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface {

  constructor(
    @InjectConnection() readonly connection: Connection,
    // Inject your repository here
    @InjectRepository(Photo) private readonly postRepository: Repository<Post>,
  ) {
    connection.subscribers.push(this);
  }

  listenTo() {
    return Post;
  }

  beforeInsert(event: InsertEvent<Post>) {
    // called before insert
  };

}
```

Comment: How can I do the same to inject whatever service? This example only uses `@InjectConnection` and `@InjectRepository`. I tried `@Inject() public myService MyService` but it turns out to be `undefined`.

Comment: Did you tried to add the `PostSubscriber `class to the providers array of your module ?